# Insert View controller before SplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, viewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to insert a RootViewController before my SplitViewController.
My code in AppDelegate is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [_window addSubview:[_viewController view]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Delegate call to my rootviewcontroller and in this i want to call to my splitviewcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SplitViewController *splitViewController = [SplitViewController initApp];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:splitViewController animated:YES];

}
```

In my SplitViewController i have this method:

```
+ (YetSplitViewController*) initApp
{
    YetSplitViewController * cont = [[YetSplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YetSplitViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (NO) 
    { 
        cont.splitWidth = 15.0;
    }
    return [cont autorelease];
}
```

After that not found good.......

My first code call from delegate to my SplitViewController:

```
@interface TemplateAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong,   nonatomic)    IBOutlet UIWindow               *window;
@property (readonly, nonatomic)    IBOutlet YetSplitViewController *splitViewController;

@property (readonly, nonatomic)    IBOutlet MasterViewController   *rootViewController;
@property (readonly, nonatomic)    IBOutlet DetailViewController   *detailViewController;

@end

@implementation TemplateAppDelegate

@synthesize window                   = _window;
@synthesize splitViewController      = _splitViewController;
@synthesize rootViewController       = _rootViewController;
@synthesize detailViewController     = _detailViewController;


- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_splitViewController release];

    [_rootViewController release];
    [_detailViewController release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if (NO) 
    { 
    _splitViewController.splitWidth = 15.0;
    }

    [_window addSubview:_splitViewController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Quote from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH7-SW1 `A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window.`

Comment: I understand it.... so if i want to add a view controller before my content of app, i have to design this view controller inside Detail View Controller and hide toolbar and navigation bar?? or is there other possibility???

Comment: You can fake a splitviewcontroller, search for e.g. mgsplitviewcontroller, use that or take that as example how to build your own.